# Changing the cleveref package language conjunction definition

Tags: cleveref

I am using the cleveref package with brazilian option. I want to change the  native brazilian range conjunction, as in "Figuras 1 a 3", to new brazilian range conjunction, as in "Figuras 1 à 3". How can I do it?

My MWE attempt:

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[brazilian]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\makeatletter
   \def\crefrangeconjunction@preamble{ \`{a}\nobreakspace}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Estas são as \cref{here:one,here:two,here:three,here:four}.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 01}
   \label{here:one}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 02}
   \label{here:two}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 03}
   \label{here:three}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 04}
   \label{here:four}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The results from that MWE are according to this figure:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ \`{a}\nobreakspace}
```

---

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[brazilian]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
%\makeatletter
%   \def\crefrangeconjunction@preamble{\"{a}\nobreakspace}%
%\makeatother

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ \`{a}\nobreakspace}

\begin{document}

Estas são as \cref{here:one,here:two,here:three,here:four}.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 01}
   \label{here:one}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 02}
   \label{here:two}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 03}
   \label{here:three}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
   \caption{Caption 04}
   \label{here:four}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. If you set the the document class option to be `brazilian` rather than `brazil`, you can omit the instruction `\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}`.

Comment: @user185511, I tested your solution and it worked fine. Thank you by help.